# How can I stop a background image from being cut off in IE8 and below?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, media-queries

I have a page with a fixed background image of a lady stuck to the bottom right corner. I am using some media queries to make it switch to the top right corner to prevent her head from being cut off when the browser window reaches the height of the image. This way it only removes the lower portion and keeps the face in view.

This works fine on CSS3 supporting browsers, but in IE8 the image stays stuck on the bottom right and her head gets cut off. Respond.js doesn't support min-height and max-height so what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Your options for older browser: calculate and set the position using JavaScript.